# Mathjax issues, where to practice.

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Is there any site where you can actually practice mathjax and where it shows how it looks like? Problem is that I can't post because the site keeps on saying" does not meet quality standards" problem is I can't see how it looks like unless it gets posted in the first place. Any help is welcome

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't get it, the link brings me to a different page with math problems

Comment: user57, if that is the case, then I better try from a different computer I guess. My language and paragraph structure can't possibly be it. The site may recognize the pc where it started...Unless it posts may mathjax literaaly with the symbols as I typed it in, without converting it to what I wanted it to look like, Then I can understand why it wouldn't do it, which brings me back to my inital question of this post.

Comment: http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm

Comment: You may have mis-interpreted the "Quality standards" message. Please see the questions with the [meta-tag:quality-filter] tag

Comment: Also, the "Ask Question" and "Your Answer" text fields are supposed to provide instant preview of the Math expressions. So it is a bit strange that you "can't see how it looks like unless it gets posted".

Comment: There is also a [formatting sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/370/79365) here on meta.

Comment: Related: [Is there a website on which I can write and display MathJax?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951/is-there-a-website-on-which-i-can-write-and-display-mathjax)

Answer (score 4):

When you click on "Ask a question" on the [main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/), preview should be displayed when you start typing the question. This is not done immediately, but when you stop typing for a second, math should be rendered; as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

If you want, you can then copy the text and save it to the file on your local computer. (Or you can work the other way round; once you have mastered TeX syntax at least a little and you have a text editor which you are comfortable with, you will probably prefer to prepare the text in your favorite editor, where you can use all shortcuts and UI you are used to, and then copy it to the browser and do minor correction there.)

This seems to be the easiest way to practice mathjax. You can also use some of the [sandbox](/questions/tagged/sandbox)es we have here.

---

Another possibility could be to prepare a html-file on your local computer and view it in your browser. Unless you want install a local copy of MathJax, you need to have access to internet and you need include the necessary scripts in the page header. See [MathJax website](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#mathjax-cdn) for more information. The rendered output might look different from what you have seen on this site, since there are many things you can configure.

Another viable possibility could be simply to prepare a html-file and with the text you need; or type in any edit field. If you install [mathjax bookmarklet](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html), you can then render you math with one click to preview it.

There are probably many other sites which use MathJax and perhaps some of themcould be used for testing, if you don't like the above options for some reasons. Many such websites are mentione [here](http://www.mathjax.org/community/mathjax-in-use/).